# Why is my timer's tolerance always halved?

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer, foundation

In my app, I'm scheduling a timer like this:

```
let period = TimeInterval(10)
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: period, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (_) in
    // Some repeating code here
})
timer.tolerance = period
```

Essentially, I want a timer to fire once in every consecutive, repeating 10 second period, but it doesn't matter when the timer fires in each individual period. However, if I set a breakpoint in the debugger for immediately after this code runs. I can see that my timer's `timeInterval` is set to 10 seconds, but the timer's `tolerance` is set to 5. I've played around with various values for `period`, but no matter the case, it seems that my timer's `tolerance` will *always* be half of its `timeInterval`. Why is that? Will this still produce the functionality I intend? If not, how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: The tolerance is about something the system _may_ do, not something it _must_ do. You cannot _force_ the timer _not_ to fire before 5 seconds after the fire-time.

Comment: I know, and that's what I'm intending. Basically instead of having the timer fire exactly every 10 seconds, I'm trying to have it once in every consecutive 10 second block. I'm trying to signal to the system it has that leeway if it wants it. However, it seems that the `tolerance` always gets set to half of the `timeInterval`, which implies that it'll always fire in the first half of each consecutive 10 second period. I'm curious as to why that's happening

Comment: Well it's taking all the leeway it needs. If that's what you intend, be happy and move on.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) *The system may enforce a maximum value for the tolerance.* so it isn't that the tolerance is *always* half the period, but rather that the most it can be is half the period, which make sense. A tolerance of 10 would allow  the timer to fire after 20 seconds, causing the next fire date to potentially "collide" with the subsequent fire date.